# run-init /sbin/init exec format error after reinstalling Ubuntu 32-bit with Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, 64-bit, 32-bit

Today I wanted to install `Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit`, because I need it for certain programs.
However during installation, the installer offered me to reinstall my old system (32-bit), so did (I know, I must have had a brain fart or what to think it would work).

Now when I want to boot my new system I get something along these lines:

```
run-init: /sbin/init: Exec Format Error
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00
```

Is it still possible to recover from this, or I'd better wipe out my current installation and start out fresh ?

Also, while googling I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1928500).
Is it true that fixing grub could help ? If so, how to do it ?

Comment: You might be able to work around that by replacing /sbin/init with the correct file, but the big question is if that is the only files which needs fixing. Personally I would check my backups (e.g. make sure /home is on its own partition, write down which one that is), and then do a clean reinstallation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone wondered I managed to fix my issue by overwriting back the 64-bit mess I made with a 32-bit copy of Ubuntu 12.10 (the broken system was untouched - I did not try to fix it anyhow except overwriting it with a 32-bit Ubuntu).
The instructions on how to overwrite the existing installation can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94542/how-can-i-repair-my-installation).
After reinstalling my system, I still had to run `update-manager -d` to update my applications, otherwise I was getting weird errors (like touchpad or wifi not working correctly).