# libX11 Segmentation fault & no login

Tags: login, segmentation-fault, gnome-session

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr with kernel (3.13.29). A couple of days ago the login screen doesn’t allow me to login. In the error log there is a

```
gnome-session error Segmentation fault on LibX11.so.6.3 error 4
```

This line occurs every time I try to log in. I have a Lenovo W530 and I am using the nouveau display driver.

I installed the gnome desktop environment, so at login I can choose the environment I want but this hasn't solved the problem. I re-installed Ubuntu and this error cropped up when I did a distribution upgrade on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Repairing the system form grub menu list after the installation if you see a grub menu try the repairing part.. there might be some important files missing or orphaned 
See 
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

for more information on boot repair and  for more questions visit following link
.

[How can I repair my installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94542/how-can-i-repair-my-installation)

Comment: Please can you explain in more detail how to repair the system from grub? Thanks, jozamm