# Language package removed

Tags: 18.04, apt, language-support

As the title says, after i tried fixing some packages while installing GLIBC 2.30 in my ubuntu 18.04, language package and tons of other ones got removed.
I checked the history log and this is what it showed:

```
Start-Date: 2021-03-09  21:06:31
Commandline: apt --fix-broken install
Requested-By: Niko (1000)
Remove: language-pack-gnome-en:amd64 (1:18.04+20190718), language-pack-gnome-es:amd64 (1:18.04+20200702), printer-driver-splix:amd64 (2.0.0+svn315-6fakesync1), bluez-cups:amd64 (5.48-0ubuntu3.4), printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 (3.17.10+repack0-5), language-pack-gnome-es-base:amd64 (1:18.04+20180712), printer-driver-postscript-hp:amd64 (3.17.10+repack0-5), localepurge:amd64 (0.7.3.4), language-pack-es-base:amd64 (1:18.04+20180712), locales:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1.4), libreoffice-l10n-es:amd64 (1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10), language-pack-en:amd64 (1:18.04+20190718), language-pack-es:amd64 (1:18.04+20200702), ubuntu-minimal:amd64 (1.417.5), libc-bin:amd64 (2.33-0ubuntu2), hplip:amd64 (3.17.10+repack0-5), language-pack-gnome-en-base:amd64 (1:18.04+20180712), printer-driver-gutenprint:amd64 (5.2.13-2), language-pack-en-base:amd64 (1:18.04+20180712), cups:amd64 (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.8), indicator-printers:amd64 (0.1.7+17.10.20171101-0ubuntu1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
End-Date: 2021-03-09  21:06:38
```

Because of this, now i can't open the terminal and every time i turn on the laptop this error appears:

```
Error found loading /etc/profile:

/usr/share/im-config/xinputrc.common: line 24: locale: command not found
/usr/share/im-config/xinputrc.common: line 24: locale: command not found

As a result the session will not be configured correctly
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible
```

I searched for the file `xinputrc.common`, and it seems that line 24 (? or something like that dosen't have a command, i think . . . i actually don't know what that means

How do i fix this problem and install the packages that got removed? or at least the usefull ones

By the way, when i try to change the language in the configuration it just [shows a black screen without the options or closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaUph.png)

Comment: You borked your system, and unless you know exactly how you "tried fixing some packages", a coarser way to get the system back on its feet will be a reinstall without reformatting - that way, your settings and data are preserved: https://askubuntu.com/questions/94542/how-can-i-repair-my-installation

Comment: I see that you had `localepurge` installed. Without knowing more, I can't help suspect that that package has something to do with it.